# How to deal with memory insufficient read by pandas in python

Tags: machine-learning, pandas

I use `pandas.read_csv` to read a huge file for machine learning, but I got memory error.

Someone recommend me to set arg `chunksize` but I need sort, random access...etc. So I need to load whole data into memory or use another way.

Some ways I think it's possible is Hadoop. Another one is incremental training, but it's like reading chunksize in `read_csv`

Or other software/library/ways can I use?

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/why.html) out

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use Dask. I used it successfully when I had to read large data with my 4GB RAM. You can get more details [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html).

To read a CSV, you can do the following:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

csv_file = 'data.csv'
df = dd.read_csv(csv_file)
```